# there are other characters in json in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jquery

I want to display information after I enter data into the database using ajax and json on codeigniter. ut the data return from json contained **double quote characters ("")**, the following controller and view ajax in codeigniter me.

controller:

```
public function simpanMenuMakanan() {
    $nama_makanan = $this->input->post('nama-menu-makanan');
    $harga_makanan = str_replace(".", "", $this->input->post('harga-makanan'));
    $jenis_makanan = $this->input->post('jenis-makanan');
    $data = array(
        'nama_makanan' => $nama_makanan,
        'harga_makanan' => $harga_makanan,
        'id_jenis_makanan' => $jenis_makanan
    );
    $simpan = $this->makanan_model->tambahMenuMakanan($data);
    if ($simpan) {
        $result = $nama_makanan . ' berhasil ditambah ke list menu makanan';
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

view javascript ajax:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>makanan/simpanmenumakanan",                        
            data: $(this).serialize(),               
            success: function(html){
                // other statement                   
                $('#result').text(html);
                // other statement
            }
        });
```

After I submit it will be out info **"xxx berhasil ditambah ke list menu makanan"**, but the problem is there is a double quote character, I want to bring up info like this without any double quotation **xxx successfully added to the list of food menu**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$nama_makanan` is not array and you want to return string from php, then you need not use `json_encode()`, just try doing:

```
//in your function
$result = $nama_makanan . ' berhasil ditambah ke list menu makanan';
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 echo json_encode($result);
```

to

```
 echo $result;
 return false;
```

json_encode is for array, specially for multidimensional associative arrays. For just string or any character or binary char, its not necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
$('#result').text(JSON.parse(html));
```

in the ajax success callback achieve the results you want?

However, it doesn't look like you are really returning JSON (I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter so I could be reading it wrong) so you could just return the raw string and then you wouldn't need the **JSON.parse**.